# Custom Dialog without title and border

Tags: android, layout

Based on the code here,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog . I am successfully able to create a custom dialog with background and buttons inside, but there's still something not right. there still a space for title bar, and there are border around the view. how to get rid of these title and border?

here is my dialog

```
Dialog pauseMenu = new Dialog(this,R.xml.pause_dialog);
pauseMenu.setContentView(R.layout.pause_menu);
return pauseMenu;
```

and here is my pause layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/pause_menu_cropped" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/pause_button_quit" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/pause_button_quit" android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/pause_button_option" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/pause_button_option" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a completely custom Dialogue/Popup in Android (change overlay colour and dialogue window layout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728990/how-to-create-a-completely-custom-dialogue-popup-in-android-change-overlay-colou)

Comment: i was just about to post a similar question and the solution is clearly answered below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Dialog cannot be created without a title. Further down in that tutorial it mentions:

> A dialog made with the base Dialog
>   class must have a title. If you don't
>   call setTitle(), then the space used
>   for the title remains empty, but still
>   visible. If you don't want a title at
>   all, then you should create your
>   custom dialog using the AlertDialog
>   class. However, because an AlertDialog
>   is created easiest with the
>   AlertDialog.Builder class, you do not
>   have access to the setContentView(int)
>   method used above. Instead, you must
>   use setView(View). This method accepts
>   a View object, so you need to inflate
>   the layout's root View object from
>   XML.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728990/how-to-create-a-completely-custom-dialogue-popup-in-android-change-overlay-colou/3736057#3736057) solves both the title and the border problem using a custom style.

Comment: looks like i understand about the title, but which part saying about the border?

Comment: this line in the answer handles that: <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_white</item>

Comment: In stead of AlertDialog we can solve this by `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ShortcutActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 90):

I think this will help you out

gameOver would be the dialog name and in setContentView it would be ur custom dialog layout

```
gameOver = new Dialog(Main.this);
gameOver.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
gameOver.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
gameOver.setCancelable(false);
gameOver.setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
```

Comment: in android version below 4.1 , the dialog width covers full screen which is bad for UI

Comment: I agree with @BasavarajHampali, this solves the problem but the width takes up the whole width... I wonder how to solve this?

Comment: This doesn't work!! :( 
   myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: +1 Very nice and neat code. This did make a trick! Thank you so much for sharing it with us.

Answer (score 9):

1. Make a class like this:

   ```
   public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
       public AlertFinishiView(Context context) {
           super(context);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
           setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
           getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
       }
   }
   ```
2. make a xml in layut folder with this name dialog

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:background="@android:color/transparent">

      <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="220dp" 
         android:layout_height="140dp" 
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"            
         android:background="@drawable/bg_custom_dialog" >

         <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:text="Button" />

      </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. add the image above in your drawable folder with name bg_custom_dialog.9.png

[image: bg_custom_dialog]

4. call in your activity:

   ```
   CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(this);
   customDialog.show();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main.this);
dialog.getWindow();
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following style in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="free_floating_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

For more options see "Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" which is part of the Android sources (since Honeycomb), or any other dialog style you based your's on.

Then simply use this style as basis to your own dialog:

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.free_floating_dialog);
myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.myContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, It works perfectly;

```
             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before     
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it work fine:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextActivity,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
alertDialog.setView(myLayout,0,0,0,0);
alertDialog.show();
```