# How to get rid of annoying title in dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog

How to get rid of annoying  title in dialog in android ?

this like i read the dialog:

```
data myDialog = new data(context);
myDialog.show();
```

this my dialog

```
public class data extends Dialog {
    public data(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    TextView txtName;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data);
        setTitle("annoying  title");
        Button btnClose;
        Button btnexit;

        txtName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText(MyParam.Fname_Lname);
        //txtName.setText(MyParam.zPhone);


        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiel);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new Close());

        btnexit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSMS);
        btnexit.setOnClickListener(new exit());
    }

    private class Close implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data.this.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private class exit implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             data.this.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

i try to remove this line `setTitle("annoying  title");`

i try this

```
myDialog.getWindow();
myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

but if i do this i see my dialog as Vertical line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before
`dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);`

You just define theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` in activity where you don't want to display title bar.

For more info [Custom Dialog without title and border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407454/custom-dialog-without-title-and-border).

[Android Dialog: Removing title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263639/android-dialog-removing-title-bar)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know where you declared the type data, but where you call the Dialog constructor do it like that:

```
new Dialog(getContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```