# change and customize Alert Dialog appearance in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

maybe it is a simple question,but its so strange! i want to change and customize my alert dialog. i use this code in style file, but  there is no changes in my alert dialog appearance.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AD_Style</item>
</style>

   <style name="AD_Style" parent="@android.widget.Holo">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/curved_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

at last, is it possible to change the buttons of alert dialog color?thanks!

```
 09-18 14:57:11.738    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:57:11.753    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:57:11.983    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:57:20.178    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:57:20.178    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:57:20.408    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:57:27.578    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:57:27.578    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:57:27.808    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:11.973    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:11.973    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:58:12.203    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:16.628    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:16.638    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:58:16.868    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:21.628    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:21.628    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:58:21.863    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:22.113    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:22.378    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:22.623    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:22.883    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:23.493    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:23.773    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:25.408    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:25.668    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:26.543    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:26.808    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:30.308    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:30.313    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:58:30.488    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:31.478    1884-2155/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:31.743    1884-2155/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:31.818    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:32.088    1884-2155/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:34.773   1884-10288/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:55.618    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:58:55.688    1884-2155/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:58:55.888    1884-2155/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:59:00.008    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:59:00.008    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 14:59:00.283    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 14:59:01.008    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 14:59:01.258    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 15:00:58.088    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 15:00:58.098    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 15:00:58.328    1884-2635/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 15:01:00.793    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 15:01:01.043    1884-2636/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
09-18 15:01:04.208    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
09-18 15:01:04.223    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
09-18 15:01:04.393    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
```

Comment: my base question is that, "alertDialogStyle" is used for changing alert dialog;s view, but it doesn;t change,why?

Comment: if i use "alertDialogTheme" or "build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this,R.style.AD_Style);" my AlertDialog covers all the screen (as Activity)with that style.WHY?

Answer (score 0):

```
View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialog);
builder.show();
```

Here i use custom Alert Dialoge

Comment: what is the "inflater"?

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: i do it, but my app has been stoped!why?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this similar question out:

[How to create a completely custom Dialogue/Popup in Android (change overlay colour and dialogue window layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728990/how-to-create-a-completely-custom-dialogue-popup-in-android-change-overlay-colo)

I used it to tweak one the other day.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i read it, but i didn;t find my answer. would you please answer me exactly?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Oh, no! Its strange, each one I try, the alert dialog covers whole screen as an activity!!!