# Changing the transparent background behind Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

How can I change the color of the semi-transparent background that is shown behind a Dialog.
The default is black and I want to make it white (with the same alpha like the default)

This is the theme I'm using for my custom dialog:

**another question** - how can I make the dialog to fill the screen width (with 20dp margin on each side)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:padding">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a xml layout and set the layout to the dialog.

This might help for the syntax: you must set the content of the dialog to a layout
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

This might help for the background: you must overwrite the theme/style
[Android Custom PopupWindow/Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773502/android-custom-popupwindow-dialog)

Comment: even when overwriting the theme - i didn't find any parameter that is responsible for the color of the half transparent layer that appears behind the popup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs