# Android PopUpWindow - How to set margin?

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow

I have this layout for PopUpWindow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"        
        android:background="@color/colorbg">    
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried adding `android:margin = "10dp"` but it won't work, it is still on the upper right with no margin at all.

Thanks.

Comment: put the extra code in xml
android:layout_gravity ="center_horizontal"

and see another criteria from the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have myself not used `PopUpWindow` but the Android docs show a method:

[`showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: There isn't a 4-parameter `showAtLocation` method in `PopupWindow`. @yin03 are you sure this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

try this **android:padding="10dip"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="10dip"        
    android:background="@color/colorbg">    
</LinearLayout>
```

or

try Custom PopupWindow
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773502/android-custom-popupwindow-dialog)

Comment: `padding` and `margin` are different things. @yin03 is asking for `margin`. You can see the difference between `padding` and `margin` if parent view's background color is different that PopupWindow.